# Why does the pressure term complicate numerical methods for Navier-Stokes Equations?

Tags: numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics, finite-differences

I'm looking to code a solver for the Navier-Stokes equations. I will be using finite differences with the method of lines.

Two questions:

1. What is the significance of the pressure term in the full 3-D NS equations in terms of numerical methods...It seems that this complicates writing a numerical method, but I'm not sure why? Any of the material I've found on this through google dives straight away into complicated schemes for addressing the problem, they don't give **a clear, simple, explanation** of what the problem actually is!
2. If we reduce the equations to 1-D does the issue with the pressure term "go away" and if so why?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you writing your own CFD code when there are many packages available, both paid and [free](http://www.openfoam.com)? From some prior work (a long time ago) in simulating accretion disks around stars and ring systems around planets (using [Zeus](http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~jstone/zeus.html)), I can tell you that you're in for a world of pain if you're going to write your own system.

Comment: Its part of an MSc thesis. And the fluid flow solver is just one section of the code that feeds other parts...it would be alot more hassle to learn to do this from scratch in a CFD package than it is to write my own solver for a very specific use case.

Comment: I think I understand what the pressure is now in any case....we don't have an evolution equation for pressure - but we can derive one from (intermediary) momentum equations, solve it and then use it in solving the (final) momentum equations for the iteration....I think I'm in a position now to code a basic solver.